# [HMVC??] Call Functions in another controller and get values

Tags: kohana-3

I am facing a situation where I need to call a function to check some status.

```
$lastupdate=Request::factory('user/getlastupdate/'.$userid.'')->execute();
```

My getlastupdate function looks like this:

```
public function action_getlastupdate($userid){

    $status=array();

    try{

$updatestatus= ORM::factory('updates')
    ->where('id', '=', $userid)
    ->where('deleted', '=',0)
    ->find_all();
//check if result returned values
$resultcount=count($updatestatus);
//if result has data
if($resultcount>0){
         foreach($updatestatus as $status)
    {
            $stat="found";
    $result= 'Profile Last Updated on'.$updatestatus->lastupdate; 

    }

}//end if result has data

//if record returned no values
else{
    $stat="missing";
$result= 'Profile Data Missing';   

}//end if resultcount>0

}//end try
catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    $stat="error";
$result="Profile Update Search Error ".$e->errors('updates');  

}///end catch
    $status['result']=$result;
    $status['stat']=$stat;

    $this->response->body(View::factory('pages/updatestatus', $status));

}//end function
```

This works but I do not want to render the view. I want to return the array status and use it from within my controller which is calling this method. How can I implement this? Does the code change if I call from the same controller vis a vis calling from a different controller?

I am using kostache templates so I need to play with the status[values] before rendering final output to my view.

Comment: Why dont use a helpers for this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send an extra parameter for your subquery which will indicate whether to auto render the view or not.

```
$lastupdate=Request::factory('user/getlastupdate/'.$userid.'/off')->execute();
```

and in your action getlastupdate check the parameter

```
action_getlastupdate($userid, $renderView = '')
{
 if( $renderView === 'off' )
 {
   $this->auto_render = FALSE;
 }
 [...]
}
```